# How to define cols in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, java, ckeditor

How I define cols in text area with ckEditor, read in many site and not found the answer. I put implicit code but it not work.

Page

```
<textarea id="ckEditor" name="ckEditor" rows="25" cols="30" ></textarea>
```

Config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.allowedContent = true;   
config.extraPlugins = 'imprimirdoc';
config.toolbar = [{name: 'styles', items:['Font','FontSize']},{name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic','Underline']},['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord','-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],{name: 'document', items:['imprimirdoc','Preview']},{name: 'editing', items: ['Find','SelectAll','-','Scayt']},'/',                                                                                                                                                        
                 {name: 'paragraph', items:['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote','-', 'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ]},
                 {name: 'insert', items:['Table','HorizontalRule','SpecialChar', 'PageBreak']},
                 {name: 'colors', items:['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
                 {name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize']}];
config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles = false;
config.contentsCss = ['contents.css'];
config.cols = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default way of resizing the text editor is described [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#resize)
Alternatively you can resize in the config too as described [here](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.width)

And for better formatting `width` and `height` are more preferred than `cols` and `rows` -- with `em` sizes and not pixels.

Comment: Thk, but it's not work, my real problem is I want define a limit of cols to not expand the TextArea and break line when limit cols coming.